# Any news on Stack Exchange? I am waiting for its release!

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have been wanting to use Stack Exchange for one of my websites. I check the website pretty often, but there is not really any updates. Does anyone know when it might be released?

Comment: ...which website are you checking? The blog? Meta? When was the last time you saw an update?

Comment: I think you are a bit behind with your info :) There is no Stack Exchange for third parties any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which website are you checking?  "Stack Exchange 1.0" [is dead](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/); the new system can be tracked at — I am not making this name up — [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange New Site Staging Area.  One of the sites proposed at Area 51, Web Apps, is already in private beta.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange home page is woefully out of date. We'll have to update it.

For the Reader's Digest version of what has been happening, this is probably the best way to catch up on the major issues:

[The Stack Overflow Blog, Category: Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/stackexchange/)

Comment: Why not link to that from the SE page?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange 1.0 was [cancelled](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). It has been replaced with Stack Exchange 2.0 and [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) where the community, and the community only, decides on which sites to create.